# rails sql find models related to self with attribute difference greater than threshold

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, model, self-reference

I have a `Person` model in rails that is related to itself:

```rb
class Person < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :children,
    class_name: "Person",
    foreign_key: :person_id

  belongs_to :mother,
    class_name: "Person",
    foreign_key: :person_id
end
```

People also have an `age` attribute representing their ages in years. I would like an ActiveRecord or SQL query to find all people with child-to-mother age discrepancies that are greater than or equal to 50 years.

(The model name here is not what I'm truly using in my app. I renamed it to simplify the problem description. However, for my actual query I will need to know if the *absolute value* of the age difference is greater than or equal to 50 years. Obviously children can't be older than their mothers so the analogy doesn't hold there.)

I have tried the following and several variants, which are all crashing:

```
    Person
      .includes(:mother)
      .where("ABS(persons.age - (SELECT age FROM persons WHERE (id = persons.person_id))) >= 50")
```

This one in particular results with a hint:

`HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.`

At first I thought that maybe the latest SQL querie's `where` clause was returning some sort of list of ages rather than just the mother's age, so I tried subscripting with a `[1]` after it to get the first element of (what should be) a single element array (if my hypothesis was correct). It was not correct - the SQL error then updated to let me know I couldn't subscript something that wasn't an array.

I'm looking for the simplest solution. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not in a position to test this but I believe reails will generate aliases for you on the fly.

Try

```
Person
      .includes(:mother)
      .where("ABS(persons.age - (SELECT age FROM mothers_persons)) >= 50")
```

Generally it's association name pluralized, underscore, table name (so if users have employees the associated table (alias) of user's employees is called `employees_users`

If the above doesn't work, you would need to create aliases manually in your SQL call.

Comment: Wow. Ruby on Rails. Thank you.